# How to find out the version of aerospike?

Tags: python-3.x, aerospike

am new to aerospike and have some problems during writing the aerospike exporter to Prometheus with python client library.
On different nodes we can have different versions of aerospike. Aerospike metrics and sometimes data format varies from version to version and I need some way to understood with which version of aerospike I am dealing.
I carefully read the documentation https://docs.aerospike.com/docs/reference/ but didn't find out how I can do it directly, only in which version some command appears.
Could you, please, hint me what I missed or where I can find it?

Answer (score 3):

You can run $asd --version from the command line on the node concerned.

root@42259b7cd10d:/# asd --version
Aerospike Enterprise Edition build 5.6.0.5
root@42259b7cd10d:/#

Answer (score 3):

The info command you need for this is [build](https://docs.aerospike.com/docs/reference/info/#build).

`asinfo -v build`

The [Aerospike Monitoring Stack](https://docs.aerospike.com/docs/tools/monitorstack/index.html) should already make use of it and signal if there are different versions running in the cluster. (The `asadm` tool uses it as well, and it also comes up when simply issuing `asinfo` without any parameters).

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I need.